# Visual Studio opens many tabs on update from SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

I have the problem that visual studio opens lots of tabs of code (files that I used recently), when I update my code from the SVN repository (with TurtleSVN).
The strange behavior also includes opening tabs for the same file as already in another tab, therefore sometimes there are lots of tabs that are opened twice after updating and have a :1 or :2 at the end.
After updating, it is always necessary to get rid of this chaos of open tabs and twice opened tabs.

Did anybody experience something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are having a problem updating a SUO file. Don't update a file ending with .suo. you have your own solution user option for files that you are working on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is not the problem, because the SUO file is not versioned and will therefore not be updated.